# GWT's KeyUpHandler is called multiple times instead of one

Tags: gwt

I've added a `KeyUpHandler` to a `Button` object as follows:

```
    button.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onKeyUp(final KeyUpEvent event1) {
             if (event.isDownArrow()) {
                  counter++;
             }
        }
    });
```

However, when I debug with SuperDev mode step by step, there are two calls to the `onKeyUp` where the initial calls has always `counter`'s initial value (0 in this case) and second call has the latest -maintained- value of `counter`. The method where I added the logic of `onKeyUp` is also marked as `synchronized`. I also tried to call `removeHandler()` method of `HandlerRegistration` right after `onKeyUp` is called. The result was that the mentioned two calls happened after first key up event, but when I did another key up event only one more call happened and further key up events area didn't happen. I assume this is sth related with superdev mode or there is some internal overhead after the compilation. What is the correct way of adding any event handlers at GWT? Do we need to always take care of each handler by calling `removeHandler()` method of HandlerRegistration?

Comment: Do you add the handler more than once?

Comment: Yes, but different handlers- MouseUpHandler and KeyUpHandler. However, I add the KeyUpHandler via a Runnable while MouseUpHandler is added when button object is created. I also realized that ClickHandler is called for both keyboard and mouse events.

Comment: the handler which you create is calling in any loop?

Comment: No not in a loop. See my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Re: your comment about multiple calls for click/mouseup/keyup

The browser "helps" for the click handler by firing it whenever any event would effectively click, either mousedown, then mouseup but no move, or various touch or keyboard events. Consider calling preventDefault() on an event you have already handled and you don't want the browser to further look at - for example, if you call this on mouseup and keyup, then those particular actions should never result in click events going off.

Comment: yea, I tried that now, but didn't change. See my updated question.